# Google Sites: adding an icon (or a text) with a link in the navigation bar

Tags: google-sites

What is the way in Google Sites to add an icon (or a text) with an associated link **in the navigation bar**?

This should be possible if I refer to [this site](https://www.ganghe.net/home) which has a text with a link in the navigation bar.

Thanks.

[image: text with link in the toolbar]